# How to insert array of values into column of postgres table using drizzle orm

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert, drizzle

**this is the result array**

```
Result(1) [
  {
    userid: '9d42ff1c-55e5-4e65-95cb-c110ae2d7196',
    workername: 'pavanrajesh365@gmail.com',
    phonenumber: 'pavanreqwo',
    scplace: '0101000020E610000070DFB42AD3AF3140FC51D499FBCD5440',
    owner: null
  }
]
```

**i am usinng drizzle orm**

```
let myuuidArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      myuuidArr.push(results[i].userid);
    }


await db.execute(sql`insert into owners (userid,ownername,phonenumber,scplace,workers) values (${id}::uuid,${email}::character varying(26),${phoneNumber}::character varying(10),ST_SetSRID(
                ST_MakePoint(
                    ${latitude},${longitude}
                ),
                4326)::geometry,ARRAY${[...myuuidArr]})`);
```

**error**

- error PostgresError: syntax error at or near "$6"

Inserting into table which the column is having type of array of text values